# Нужна ли в Python функция nonlocals() наряду с globals(), locals()?

Tags: python, globals

Иногда удобно использовать функцию **globals()**. В примере ниже я создаю словарь функций, используя некоторые соглашения, а именно - первый символ имени функции должен совпадать с ключом:

```
def a_fun(c):
    print(c, 'from a_fun')


def b_fun(c):
    print(c, 'from b_fun')

def fun():
    fun_dict = dict.fromkeys({'a', 'b'})
    return {key: globals()[key + '_fun'] for key in fun_dict}

fun()['a'](33), fun()['b'](44)
```

код прекрасно себе работает и выдает:

```
33 from a_fun  
44 from b_fun
```

Но вот при описании класса так не получается. Мне удалось только так:

```
class fabric():

    def __a_fun(self, c):
        print(c, 'from __a_fun')


    def __b_fun(self, c):
        print(c, 'from __b_fun')

    def fun(self):
        # print(locals())
        # print(globals())
        return {'a': self.__a_fun, 'b': self.__b_fun}

z = fabric()

z.fun()['a'](33)
```

что дает

```
33 from __a_fun
```

Проблема в том, что __a_fun и __b_fun отсутствуюьт в словарях **locals()** и **globals()**.
Подскажите, можно ли это реализовать по аналогии с первым примером?  Идея в том, чтобы не менять код при добавлении очередного варианта обработки данных. Ну если что-то поменялось -  я просто добавлю еще одну функцию в файл и не нужно менять в другом месте.
То есть вопрос об автоматическом заполнении словаря с функциями внутри класса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все названия методов класса можно достать из `self.__class__.__dict__` и начинаться они там будут с `self.__class__.__name__`:

```
class fabric():

    def __a_fun(c):
        print(c, 'from __a_fun')

    def __b_fun(c):
        print(c, 'from __b_fun')

    def fun(self):
        fun_dict = dict.fromkeys({'a', 'b'})
        return {key: self.__class__.__dict__['_' + self.__class__.__name__ + '__' + key + '_fun'] for key in fun_dict}


z = fabric()

z.fun()['a'](33), z.fun()['b'](44)
```

Вывод:

```
33 from __a_fun
44 from __b_fun
```

Вариант, чтобы не прописывать словарь, а всё брать из класса:

```
    def fun(self):
        postfix = '_fun'
        cut = -len(postfix)
        return {k[cut-1:cut]: v for k,v in self.__class__.__dict__.items() if callable(v) and k.endswith(postfix)}
```

Comment: Думаю перфектно будет вычленить все ключи из __a_fun, __b_fun, ... и автоматически собрать ключи для fun_dict.  Тогда все должно работать без изменений в коде, да?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets Не совсем понял мысль, но можно, например, назвать все функции с окончанием `_fun` и пройтись по ключам словаря `self.__class__.__dict__`, посмотрев, что там заканчивается на `_fun`. Как-то так.

Comment: Я это и имел ввиду  ))

Comment: @VasylKolomiets Добавил такой вариант )